# Event listeners on elements in a Vue Modal: are they destroyed when the Modal is closed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm adding an event listener for a DOM element in a component that exists within a Vue modal:

```
this.$bvModal.show('modal-upload-file')
this.$nextTick(() => {
        document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('focus', () => {
          document.getElementsByClassName('file-uploads')[0].classList.add('btn-outline-primary')
          document.getElementsByClassName('file-uploads')[0].classList.remove('btn-primary')
        })
      })
```

The listener works great but I'd like to remove it when the Modal component closes; my application is an SPA and won't need it on other pages.  Though I know that I can just use removeEventListener, my question is whether the event listeners are destroyed automatically when the Modal is closed since the elements inside the Modal no longer exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the node is destroyed (or removed from the DOM and never used again) then it'll be garbage collected along with any event listeners attached to it.

When using Vue, accessing the DOM manually and attaching event listeners like that is a red flag. Is there any reason why you can't do it the "Vue way"?

Comment: I very much wanted to do it the Vue way!  The problem that I was having was that the DOM element I needed to access was tucked away in a component that was part of an NPM package which was then inside of a Vue modal.  I couldn't think of a way to access this element that was part of the package without resorting to Vanilla JS. But if there is design pattern I'm unaware of, then I'm all ears.

Comment: I understand sometimes it's necessary when you need to add/change functionality from a library when it does not provide a way to do so. In these cases, it's best to keep the "hacky" code as isolated as possible, perhaps extract it into a separate method and document what it does. Also don't query the entire DOM in case there's another `#file` element elsewhere, just query from the modal element like `document.querySelector('.modal #file')`. Limit the scope of the hack as much as possible.

Comment: In this particular case there won't be another #file so I'm not concerned.  However, I think that moving the hack to another method in another file that I import (maybe a "hacks.js" file with documentation) is sound advice.